# What's become of the author Dan Simmons?

Tags: authors, dan-simmons

What's become of the author Dan Simmons? I know he suffered a head injury, but that was several years ago. His website had disappeared, and Googling hasn't turned up any info newer than 2019.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have release date of 1st May '23 listed on Amazon (Disclaimer: other rivers are available).

Comment: @JiminyCricket unfortunately I don’t think you can take that date seriously. Omega Canyon is no longer even listed by the publisher Little Brown/Hachette. I fear it’s just a ghost in a lot of inventory systems. My surmise is that the injury may have ended his career, but I was hoping for news.

Answer (score 5):

Back in February of this year he answered a question about OMEGA CANYON and its release date on his Facebook page. He said:

> “It's not out yet. Nor is it quite finished. But it's alive. IT'S ALIVE!!! IT'S ALIVE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! “

You can also find an excerpt from the book on his Facebook page from 2019. Just do a search for “Omega Canyon” and you will find it among other posts including the one above.

https://www.facebook.com/profile/100002913803528/search/?q=Omega%20Canyon

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's good to have some news, but you could improve this answer with a link to the post and a screenshot of the content in case it is made private or deleted.

Comment: (I saw that *Omega Canyon* had a May 2023 release date, but it also had release dates in 2021 and 2019, so I wasn't holding my breath.)

Comment: I can't find that comment on his facebook page, nor on the fan-page on Facebook that he used to frequent.

Comment: See if this link helps… https://www.facebook.com/profile/100002913803528/search/?q=Omega%20Canyon

Comment: If you expand the comments at the given link, there is indeed a 8 week old comment post by the author. https://i.imgur.com/U7ezS7d.png

Comment: I was happy to see that he'd updated his Facebook profile picture in February, so he's alive and at least occasionally online. I found the excerpt he put up in 2019, but I sure as heck can't find any comments from Mr. Simmons about the book still being alive. Maybe my Facebook-fu is weak. I'd love it to be true, but I remain skeptical. As I said above the book is no longer listed at his publisher's website.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant - I'm in the same boat. I've followed the link but I can't see the quoted comment.

Comment: Sounds like it's going to be a monster.

Comment: If you click on this link: https://i.imgur.com/U7ezS7d.png  Dan's quote is the first one under the question.

Comment: @Greg thanks for that, but there isn't a year marked on that screen capture. Over the years Mr. Simmons has put out several such assurances, are you sure it isn't from an earlier year? Could you possibly link to the actual source rather than a screen capture?

Comment: @Charles, I saw the post when it was posted in February and it says that it was posted 10 weeks ago making it a post in February. Also, the date out beside the question regarding OMEGA CANYON says February 19. All other search results for “Omega Canyon” show a date and a year like Dan’s post further down of his sneak preview has the date of “March 17, 2019”. The ones made right above it regarding Omega Canyon only have the month and day because they were posted this year. Sorry if this isn’t proof enough. By the way, I also don’t think the book will ever see print sadly.